# Show window for transfering and extracting files in KDE Plasma 5

Tags: kde, window, filemanager, transfer, plasma-5

Usually in DE's when you start copy files there window appear at center of screen (progress of copy process). But in Kubuntu 18.04 it only gonna be shown at the notification area at the panel. It's confusing: sometime I think that there some bug and copying process didn't begin. So I repeat it several times, until I notice progress circle on the panel.
How could I make it less confusing ?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

**KDE Frameworks 5 and Plasma 5 notifications**

As default the plasma 5 desktop is showing copy progress in the task buttons and in the notifications:

[image]

Task manager setting: "Show progress and status information in task buttons"

[image]

Notification Settings: "Track file transfer and other jobs"

[image]

If both (task button progress & notification transfer) settings are disabled the traditional file transfer window will be shown:

[image]

Plasma setting changes may need to restart the plasmashell - logout and login.

KDE Forums: Dolphin not showing native file transfer dialog - https://forum.kde.org/viewtopic.php?f=224&t=135264

Comment: Your instructions worked perfectly on Kubuntu 18.04, thank you very much for the detailed answer and mentioning the need to logout & login.

Comment: I'm just trying out Kubuntu (this works in 18.10 as well) for the first time and this was one of very few minor issues/preferences for me. As a side note for anyone else that struggled to find these settings, right clicking on the "task bar" will get you to the "Task Manager Settings" and right clicking on the circle "i" can get you to the "Notifications Settings". I couldn't seem to find the task manager part at first. Thanks again for info.

Comment: Is it possible to make the transfer dialog showing on top of all other windows immediately after copy starts?

Comment: to  spucktek: The window rules may help - KDE System Settings > Window Management > Window Rules

Answer (score 2):

In later versions of Plasma (e.g. 5.23) those settings are grouped under "Notifications"
[image]